# +CME ERROR: 100 when executing USSD command in perl

Tags: perl, serial-port, gsm, at-command, ussd

I'm using this script to check the credit on my SIM card using USSD command it works fine using a an old Nokia phone connected with USB cable to my PC , the issue is the same script is not working when I use this device : 
[image: Huawei USB device] ,
 what possibly might be wrong ? here is my Perl script and please note that communication is working fine through the COM7 port:

```
    use strict;
    use Win32::SerialPort 0.11;
    my $ob = Win32::SerialPort->start ("config.cfg") || die;
    $ob->write("AT+CUSD=1,\"*200#\",15");
    sleep 5;
    my $credit = $ob->input;
    my($directory) = $credit =~ /(.*) DA/;
    print "$directory\n";
```

my configuration file `config.cfg`:

```
Win32::SerialPort_Configuration_File -- DO NOT EDIT --
\\.\COM7
CFG_1,none
eol,10
clear,-@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@-
RCONST,0
istrip,0
CFG_2,none
XOFFCHAR,0
PARITY_EN,0
WCONST,200
intr,3
U_MSG,1
STOP,1
XONLIM,0
erase,8
XONCHAR,0
BINARY,1
RTOT,0
echonl,0
XOFFLIM,0
icrnl,0
inlcr,0
READBUF,2097152
igncr,0
EOFCHAR,0
WRITEBUF,0
RINT,4294967295
ocrnl,0
bsdel, 
opost,0
echoke,1
PARITY,none
HNAME,localhost
echoctl,0
CFG_3,none
EVTCHAR,0
icanon,0
isig,0
HADDR,0
E_MSG,1
DATA,8
DVTYPE,none
echo,0
quit,4
s_eof,26
s_kill,21
ERRCHAR,0
onlcr,1
ALIAS,COM7
HSHAKE,rts
DATYPE,raw
echok,1
echoe,1
BAUD,9600
WTOT,10
```

Comment: "the same script is not working" is a terrible problem report. What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Is there an error message?

Comment: It would be also good to know the exact model name of the device you showed us, even better if you know the modem device within it. In this way we can search for the relevant AT command guide. Be aware that the behavior (especially when you have to deal with verbose errors) can depend on the modem model.

Comment: Furthermore, USSD is a service provided by the network operator, and the behavior might depend on it. What is the `"*200#"` command supposed to do? Did you use exactly the same SIM?

Comment: In `$ob->write("AT+CUSD=1,\"*200#\",15");` you didn't append the command line terminator `\r`. Am I wrong?

Comment: `+CME ERROR: 100` means "unknown". Some devices have an AT interface timeout that occurs in case there's data in AT serial port but it is not terminated. That's why the presence of the AT terminator is actually really relevant.

Comment: @Asmoun still need the answer?

Comment: @Spidy yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am a javascript guy, but this is pretty much the steps to fix the issue.

first run this AT :  `AT+CSCS="IRA"`

goto http://www.rednaxela.net/pdu.php

under the "PDU SMS message creator", set `alphabet size: 7`

clear the 1st box and enter your USSD code (eg. *124#) , click convert

in the 2nd box, copy the last line (eg. *124# -> AA988C3602)

add it to your ussd section:  AT+CUSD=1,"AA988C3602", 15

run

to decode the response, goto http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288

paste the response in "USSD Entry/Display" box,make sure GSM 7bit packed is selected, then click convert

this is a javascript library for the 7bit pdu conversion -> https://github.com/IAmDarush/ussd-pdu-text-converter

can't find one for perl